# Bundling duplicate content in file on asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, bundle, asp.net-core-2.0

I created an empty project of **asp.net core** and added **BuildBundlerMinifier** to test how it works now.

I added two files to be combined, css and js but when i add them to the bundler it duplicates the content of the second file into the first one.

This is only for test, but I do not understand what is wrong.

Project config:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="BuildBundlerMinifier" Version="2.6.362" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup> 

</Project>
```

bundleconfig:

```
[
    {
        "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/test.js",
        "inputFiles": [
            "wwwroot/js/test.js",
            "wwwroot/js/testtest.js"
        ]
    },
    {
        "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/customcss.css",
        "inputFiles": [
            "wwwroot/css/customcss.css",
            "wwwroot/css/customcss1.css"
        ],

        "minify": {
            "enabled": true,
            "renameLocals": true
        },
        "sourceMap": false
    }
]
```

test.js file has:

```
function myfunction(hola) {
    //Hola
    console.log(hola);
}
```

testtest.js file has:

```
function testFileTwo(valueP) {
    //Hi
    console.log(valueP);
}
```

Why would it combine the files and rewrite them, this behavior only need to be done on the browser, I think.

test.js automatic filling with this:

```
function myfunction(hola) {
    //Hola
    console.log(hola);
}
function testFileTwo(valueP) {
    //Hi
    console.log(valueP);
}
function testFileTwo(valueP) {
    //Hi
    console.log(valueP);
}
function testFileTwo(valueP) {
    //Hi
    console.log(valueP);
}
function testFileTwo(valueP) {
    //Hi
    console.log(valueP);
}
function testFileTwo(valueP) {
    //Hi
    console.log(valueP);
}
function testFileTwo(valueP) {
    //Hi
    console.log(valueP);
}
function testFileTwo(valueP) {
    //Hi
    console.log(valueP);
}
```

Comment: Does this happen to both bundles? JS and CSS? and can you please show the two JS files you're bundling? (test.js and testtest.js) just to make sure you're not having circular dependency :)

Comment: Don't put pictures of code in your question, you need to put in the code text in then highlight it and press the toolbar button `{ }` to format it correctly. Images cause issues with searching for questions and for people on mobile viewing your question.

Comment: Yes! it happens in both files, **css** and **js**. The dependency is in projectconfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because you have the same name for the bundle result and for the bundle input. Could change it and test?

Comment: That was the problem, when I changed the output name to a new one, it worked. Thanks!